# Why do people wear hats when they Pray?

Tags: salat

This has been another issue I continuously wonder about, when people are just about to offer prayer or when they enter a Mosque they put on hats similar to the one in the picture below:

[image]

1. What's its purpose? (Is it some sort of Hasanat booster)?
2. Is there any narraration about specific dresses for prayer (Although I know that there is no Islamic dress as long as the dress is compliant with the Islamic teaching i.e. covering the awrah)

If you believe that wearing the hat is Sunnah or mandatory than please provide the relative evidence!

Also take into consideration the environment the prophet PBUH, where a hat may have been used as a form of protection from sun rays!

Comment: What nice query. Accidentally it was my question as well. Though I reckon it is a kind of Sunnah, but not sure about that. Hope to see appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0):

If in short i try to explain,
**There are two point of views** about hats, or more precisely covering heads (for men, for women it is mandatory for them) when praying.
 **1. It is mandatory** and prayer will not be valid without it.(this is based on the point that prophet peace be upon him used to cover his head all the time, and there is no proof of him praying without covering the head.)
 **2. It is better** to cover head for men when praying. But it is not mandatory.(This claim is based on some evidences which shows some people prayed without covering their heads in front of prophet and prophet said nothing(This is considered to be approval). So, it is not mandatory but sunnah to cover the heads when praying.)
 As you didn't mentioned you need some proofs or actual references to the evidence, and your question seems to be only requiring some basic understanding of what it is. So, i have not included any details of both point of views.
**PS:** Personally i go with second point of view, as it is more logical.

Comment: Just a small advice, before attempting to answer, please look if the question has already been answered else where. Why waste you're effort if you think you don't have a better answer than the existing ones, but which are elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

aww,

The hat is sunnah. There are many hadiths which show that the prophet (Saw) wore a hat in prayer.

Wail ibn Hajr mentions how he looked at the congregation and they were wearing hats (http://sunnah.com/abudawud/2/338).

In another hadith, the Prophet (Saw) says that "The difference between us and the polytheists is that we wear turbans over CAPS" - the polytheists wore turbans without caps, while the Muslims wore caps first, and turbans on top. Thus, the wearing of caps is sunnah (http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/24/73 - note that Albani calls this narration weak, but his gradings are contested).

Also, in Hajj, the Prophet (saw) instructed everyone not to wear hats, which shows that it was normal for them to wear hats. This is further proof that hats were worn.

Furthermore, there is a hadith in which Umar (ra) or the Prophet (Saw)'s hat falls off, which again indicates that hats were worn.

The large body of hadiths on the wearing of caps indicate that it is sunnah to wear them.

Some people say that hats were worn outside prayer but not in prayer. This is unlikely. If it were true, there would be lots of hadiths describing how the Prophet (Saw) and sahaba took off their hats before praying. Such hadiths don't exist, which means this didnt happen.

some more hadiths on hats are here: http://sunnah.com/search/?q=%D9%82%D9%84%D9%86%D8%B3%D9%88%D8%A9

wwb